# The envelope for the extremals of $\cos((n+1) \arccos x)-\cos((n-1) \arccos x)$ forms an ellipse.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials, envelope

The Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind is defined on $[-1, 1]$ by
$$T_n(x) = \cos(n \arccos x).$$
Prove that the envelope for the extremals of $T_{n+1}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$ forms an ellipse.
[image]

The conclusion is obvious from the picture, and we know that the extremals are "almost" but not lying on $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$, but I think it is not easy to strictly illustrate this property and derive the final conclusion (The extremal is the zeros of $x\sin(n\cos^{-1}(x))+n\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(n\cos^{-1}(x))=0$, and I think the "envelope" is somewhat hard to describe).
Are there any ways to strictly prove the correctness of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = T_{n + 1}(x) - T_{n - 1}(x)$. Verify that the turning points of $f_1$ and $f_2$ and the turning point $(0, 2)$ of $f_3$ lie on the ellipse $11 x^2/9 + y^2/4 = 1$. Verify that the other turning points of $f_3$ do not lie on that ellipse. It follows that the turning points of $f_n$ do not lie on any ellipse. What is true is that the ellipse $x^2 + y^2/4 = 1$ is the envelope of the curves $y = f_n(x)$.

Comment: You're right, the $x^2+y^2/4=1$ is actually tangent to all $f_n(x)$. The original problem use "envelope for the extremals", I think maybe the original problem is asking us to prove that when $n\rightarrow\infty$ the extremals form an ellipse, which is not hard.